# Overlap absolutely positioned sibling div without specifying background color on relative div

Tags: css, angular, dom, css-position

Trying to create a swipe to action list component.

```
<div class="list-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content">
            Some Content 1
        </div>
        <div class="action">
            Delete Action
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="content">
            Some Content 2...
        </div>
        <div class="action">
            Delete Action
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Action div** is absolutely positioned with z-index less than of **content div**.

Goal here to make **content div** overlap the absolutely positioned **action div**, without providing the `background-color` to **content div**. If user swipe the list, content div is translated in X direction, to show the action below it.

Link to sample https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdgct9

Notice that second row's content doesn't uses any background color, because of which action is visible.

Are there any other ways to achieve this?

Comment: So you want to have the same scenario in second row which is available now only in first row?? Am I right??

Comment: @ManirajMurugan yes

Comment: Hope this helps.. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gfm6sv

Answer (score 0):

Edited your [stackblitz](https://angular-xdgct9.stackblitz.io). so that initially the action class is set to have display:none. After animating, the css property display is set to block

```
anim() {
  requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    this.value -= 1;
    if (this.value > -50) {
      this.anim();
      (document.querySelector('.action') as HTMLElement).style.display = 'block'
  }
});
```

and in your css

```
.action{
  ...
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Just saw that you let the stackblitz be editable, is that what you were looking for?

Comment: wanted to hide the action div until swipe occurs, don't want to make it visible on load.

Comment: Check now, display none and then block gradually as the animation occurs.